# Telegram request "fopen failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Tags: javascript, php, telegram

I am trying to send messages to my telegram bot. Exactly name variable can't allow me to do it.

```php
    $arr = array(
      $phoneFieldset => $phone,
      $nameFieldset => $name,
      $messageFieldset => $message,
    );
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
      $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };
    
    $request = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}";
    
    echo $request;
    
    $sendToTelegram = fopen($request,"r");
```

The request echo output, when the script fails:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botMYTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=-449128489&parse_mode=html&text=Телефон: 123%0AИмя: de%0AСообщение: 123213%0A
```

> Warning: fopen(https://api.telegram.org/botMYTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=-449128489&parse_mode=html&text=**Телефон:**  123%0A**Имя:**  de%0A**Сообщение:**  123213%0A): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\nginx\html\scripts\php\send-message-to-telegram.php on line 61
> Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!

Line 61 is the one containing the `fopen()`.

The request echo output, when the script works:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botMYTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=-449128489&parse_mode=html&text=Телефон: 123123%0AСообщение: 1213123%0A
```

Comment: It looks like you have some unencoded characters in your "text" parameter. You could try adding `$txt = rawurlencode($txt)` just before using the value in your request string.

Comment: Also, is it me, or are both of your output string examples identical?

Comment: Ty, it solved my problem. I used urlencode() to russian strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you need to encode Cyrillic characters to URL entities. You can do that using `rawurlencode($txt)`. See full code below:

```php
    $arr = array(
      $phoneFieldset => $phone,
      $nameFieldset => $name,
      $messageFieldset => $message,
    );
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
      $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };

    $txt = rawurlencode($txt)  // To encode cyrillic entities

    $request = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}";
    
    echo $request;
    
    $sendToTelegram = fopen($request,"r");
```

P.S. Taken from @ed-lucas comment for others who will search for answer.